# laravel 5.3, php artisan make:auth having Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

**fresh installed laravel 5.3**

*executed the following..*

- php artisan make:auth
- configured database
- php artisan migrate

whiling logging out not working & console error appears..

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-gzip: "http://localhost:8000/css/app.css".
```

app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I've never come across that error and I did the exact same process this morning. Are you sure that's *all* you've done?

Comment: issue fixed i had enabled zlib.output_compression=On in xampp before. now commented out its working fine... Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file: `AddType text/css .css` - This will send the correct headers rather than the x-gzip one.

Comment: issue fixed i had enabled zlib.output_compression=On in xampp before. now commented out its working fine... Thank You!